# How to make a case insensitive match on a phrase with special characters?

Tags: regex

I want to match `[[Party Signatures]]` following regardless of the case.  So the test text could be: `I would like to collect [[party signatureS]] tonight`.

I was able to make a match without the square brackets (`(?i)\bparty signatures\b`), but I can't figure out how to include the square brackets in the search.

Comment: `/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/gmi` should do it?

Comment: @SamuelG Not sure what I am looking at here.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Just add the brackets in the regex: `(?i)\[\[party signatures\]\]`, word boundaries are useless here.

Comment: @Toto That did the trick

Comment: @SamuelG I am having to pass the regex pattern into a 3rd party library - so not sure what they are using.

Comment: OK, as per comment above: `\[\[(.*?)\]\]` should do the trick - small snippet in answer for you to check, I see you a .NET peep

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the square brackets and then do a non-greedy match on the content between the brackets.

Escape special characters using `\` before the brackets and create a capture group to grab anything between zero or more times brackets using `(*.?)`

```
        // ignorecare and process multiple lines
        var regex = new Regex(@"\[\[(.*?)\]\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var matches = regex.Matches("I would like to collect [[party signatureS]] tonight [[party signatureS]]");

        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nope");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using C# this pattern might help:

- set case-insensitive modifier
- look for 2 opening square brackets
- look for any word characters or spaces
- look for 2 closing square brackets

```regex
(?i)\[{2}[\w ]*\]{2}
```